# AJAX loading image barely visible

Tags: ajax

I have a simple issue. I am posting data from a form to my DB using an AJAX request. I have coded in a loading GIF using the **beforeSend** and **complete** commands in my AJAX request.

```
<script>
           $(function(){
            //email the link    
            $("##emailTicket#get_active_tickets.ticket_id#").submit(function(){
               // prevent native form submission here
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        data: $('##emailTicket#get_active_tickets.ticket_id#').serialize(),
                        url: "actionpages/email_dashboard_ticket.cfm",
                        beforeSend: function(){
                            $('.loader').show()
                        },
                        complete: function(){
                             $('.loader').hide();
                        },
                        success: function() {
                          $("##emailTicketResponse#get_active_tickets.ticket_id#").html("");
                          $("##emailTicketResponse#get_active_tickets.ticket_id#").append( "Ticket successfully sent." );
                          }    
                    });
                    return false;           
                });

            });
            </script>
```

Everything seems to be working correctly however the loading GIF only flashes for a split second because the request doesn't take long at all to complete. Sometimes you can't even see it and users are confused if clicking the submit button actually did anything.

Is there a way to delay the 'complete' part of the function so that the animated GIF appears on the screen longer?

```
complete: function(){
$('.loader').hide();
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by modifying my **complete** code in my function and adding a delay in milleseconds:

```
complete: function(){
    $('.loader').hide(3000);
},
```